# Lock on an class member vs having that object initialized in class' method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, synchronization

So, I have this service, let's call it "MyService". MyService has one public method, which is "executeBatchJob", as the name says, it will execute a batchJob, in short, retrieving some data from a database, at some point, I have an object that is very much like an entity, with an ID and a list of records. In my method executeBatchJob, some checks are made, and when some conditions are met, the entity is written somewhere and re-initialized (new ID, different records), but note that it happens in private methods called by executeBatchJob. Under other conditions, in different private method, records are added to the list of records hold by the entity.

My question is: As the service might be called by several process: is it better to have that entity declared as a class member (private readonly) and lock it when needed, and then having a method that will clean the entity's state for the next process. Or is it better to have this object declared and used in my method executeBatchJob, but dragging the object around through all the private methods as the state of the object can change at several "level" ?

To illustrate you what I was explaining :

Here is myEntity :

```
public class MyEntity
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public List<Record> Records { get;  set; }

 public void CleanUp(int newId)
 {
     Id = newId;
     Records.Clear();
 }
}
```

Here is myService with a lock :

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
 private readonly MyEntity _myEntity;

 public MyService()
 {
     _myEntity = new MyEntity();
 }

 public void executeBatchJob(int batchId)
 {
     //some code
     lock(_myEntity)
     {
        // More code and call to some private method
        _myEntity.CleanUp();
     }

     // still more code
 }
}
```

Or with the second option :

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{

 public MyService()
 {
 }

 public void executeBatchJob(int batchId)
 {
     MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

     APrivateMethodInExecuteBatchJob(myEntity);
     // more code

 }

 private returnResult APrivateMethodInExecuteBatchJob(MyEntity myEntity)
 {
      // Some manipulation of myEntity
      // some code, with another call to a private method with myEntity, and manipulation of myEntity

      // ... write the entity
      myRepository.write(myEntity);

 }
}
```

To give more context, as far as I know, each time the entity will be written, it has to be cleaned up, in the second option, I can just do a "new MyEntity()" (which makes more sense on a business point of view).

To me, the second solution is more logic and appropriate, BUT, I'll have several private methods that will move the object, sometimes just to pass it to another private method without any other manipulation than "passing" it to that other private method... Which is not clean at all...

That's why I need your advice / opinion on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IDisposable` interface,  its purpose is exactly what you are doing

```
public class MyEntity: IDisposable;
```

Then you can go with the second option with the using keyword.

You can check an example here on what and how to implement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Example with you code:

```
public void executeBatchJob(int batchId)
{

    using (vMyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();) 
    {
       APrivateMethodInExecuteBatchJob(myEntity);
       // more code
    }

}
```

Generally, try to avoid using locks when it's not needed. It might create race conditions that will make your application less responsive.

Comment: Thanks, i'm still new to C sharp and .Net, I've forget about the IDisposable keyword, even that I've used it recently.

Answer (score 1):

If the entity is not supposed to keep it's state it's in my opinion far superior to have idempotent methods as in option 2. If you can make the methods static you'll end up with a much simpler architecture.

As you've identified you will have issues where you need to lock your resource in option 1 and as long as the state is thrown away during cleanup there's no point in that headache.

Only reason I can see for something like option 1 is if the entity is built up from transactions that is not cleared away between uses or if the entity is for some reason very expensive to create.